# How to add JavaFX javadocs to vscode when not using build tools

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javafx

I would like to add the documentation for JavaFX to vscode so that when I hover over functions it tells me what they do. I have downloaded the Javadocs from the JavaFX website but I don't know what to do with them now. I'm creating my projects without any build tools through vscode. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try adding the following configuration in your `setting.json` file.

```json
"java.project.referencedLibraries": {
    "include": [
        "lib/**/*.jar",
        "%PATH_TO_FX%/lib/*.jar"
    ],
    "sources": {
        "%PATH_TO_FX%/lib/javafx.base.jar": "%PATH_TO_FX%/src.zip",
        "%PATH_TO_FX%/lib/javafx.controls.jar": "%PATH_TO_FX%/src.zip",
        "%PATH_TO_FX%/lib/javafx.fxml.jar": "%PATH_TO_FX%/src.zip",
        "%PATH_TO_FX%/lib/javafx.graphics.jar": "%PATH_TO_FX%/src.zip",
        "%PATH_TO_FX%/lib/javafx.media.jar": "%PATH_TO_FX%/src.zip",
        "%PATH_TO_FX%/lib/javafx.swing.jar": "%PATH_TO_FX%/src.zip",
        "%PATH_TO_FX%/lib/javafx.web.jar": "%PATH_TO_FX%/src.zip",
        "%PATH_TO_FX%/lib/javafx.swt.jar": "%PATH_TO_FX%/src.zip"
    }
}
```

`%PATH_TO_FX%` is your javafx folder path.

**another possible approach**

for example, a project like this:

```
/project
 /lib
  test-1.0.0.jar
 /doc
  test-1.0.0-javadoc.jar
```

add in your `.classPath` :

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/test-1.0.0.jar">
  <attributes>
    <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="jar:platform:/resource/project/doc/test-1.0.0-javadoc.jar!/" />
  </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

**Update：**

Open the command palette with **ctrl + shift + p**, type `settings`. You will see that there are three `settings.json` files that can be opened.

[image]

**Open Settings**: VS Code global settings.

**Open Workspace Settings**: Only affects the current job.

**Open Default Settings**: All default settings of vscode.

So, putting the settings in the `settings.json` that opens after selecting **Open Settings** will have an effect forever.

But there is one thing to note: if there is the *same setting command* in the `settings.json` of the workspace, the global settings will be overwritten (only valid for the workspace).