# How to add dependencies without build tools in vscode for javafx

Tags: javafx

I created javafx project with Eclipse IDE but now I'm moved on to vscode. I can run it through a manual command:
`$java -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-21.0.1\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -cp bin application.Main`, but vscode doesn't recognize javafx so there's a lot of red lines and I want it to be fixed.

I tried things that introduced in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72625811/how-to-add-javafx-javadocs-to-vscode-when-not-using-build-tools) but referencedLibraries setting in setting.json file doesn't work. Actually, this setting doesn't even make changes in java project view.

I also tried configuring .classpath file and it actually recognizes jar files, but the problem is when I 'run java', javafx jar files are added to -cp option, not --module-path option, which leads to error for running javafx project.

So I want to know adding dependencies in vscode which makes vscode to recognize the jar files and to add the command line option for --module-path. I'm not using build tools.

Comment: Getting started documentation at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-VSCode) tells you how to use JavaFX with VS Code, I advise that you follow the instructions there (first with the example hello world project on the site, and then adapt the steps for your application).  I advise using build tools (Maven or Gradle, and Maven if you are not familar with Gradle), integrated with the IDE rather than relying on IDE specific build configurations (the openjfx link informs you how to do that).

Comment: @jewelsea thank you, I followed the instruction and now all the problems I mentioned is solved, maybe the path to the setting was a problem. by the way, you recommend using build tool, can you tell me why? because I just thought that while learning, not relying on such a tool and manually setting those will be helpful.

Comment: It is not efficient, effective or portable to develop without using a build tool.  It is better to use a tool that will assist you, gaining knowledge and experience with that.  Consider learning [long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division) vs using a calculator to help you divide.  The calculator is more accurate and efficient and the long division skills will never help you use a calculator.  Manually configuring a project in an IDE is akin to using a [slide rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_rule) instead of a calculator, i.e. it is obsoleted by integrating build tools